# Where is the positive terminal on the laser pointer

Tags: battery

I want to connect this to wires , I know where the negative terminal is on this ( the spring) but I can’t figure out where the positive terminal is, I can’t find and answer online anywhere else either.  It’s a blue laser. Please help[image]

Comment: My guess would be the case of the laser diode if it came out of a laser pen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The positive terminal is the leg connected to the led diode case, which is in contact with the metallic led holder.

On the board this leg is soldered on the opposite side of the components.

More details here: https://www.datasheetarchive.com/pdf/download.php?id=3986888527796ddb5524529252bea59f4ce640&type=P&term=Kingbor%2520LED